# Changing amperage without changing voltage

Tags: frequency, amperage

I know this has been covered before but I don't see an answer for what I want to do.
Using a 12 volt car battery I want to power up a wound coil to produce a magnetic field.  I would like  to have a steady current as I plan on using a pulse generator to produce a frequency in the 300 to 900 Hz range.
I have a trigger circuit that will take the pulsed 12 volt source directly to the coil. 
At least I think it will.
If I just hook the battery to the coil I believe I would be creating a dead short.   So I want to limit the amperage draw without inducing an unwanted frequency.
Is this possible?

Comment: Change the load

Comment: Need to know your coil inductance and resistance.  Or at least, weight of copper and number of turns.  But, it sounds like a job for a high-freq switching regulator.  Otherwise, you'll end up with giant heat sinks, boiling hot series-resistors, etc.  At least feed the coil some narrow voltage pulses, and use scope to observe speed of current ramps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the inductance, the current depends on the frequency. The current is most at DC then drops as the frequency increases. Of course reducing the voltage also reduces the current.